# conda info conda list command gives errors

Tags: shell, anaconda, conda

Commands like conda list and conda info is not working. They were working before but suddenly not works. Maybe I did something but I don't remember.

So I already tried 
conda update conda which gives me

```
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1043, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .install import install
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
    libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1335, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1046, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1090, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1101, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1171, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .tarball import CondaTarBZ2 as _CondaTarBZ2
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\tarball.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libarchive
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
    libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

conda update anaconda also gives me errors.

When I try conda info it gives me :

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1043, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
        module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
        from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
        from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
        from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 3, in <module>
        from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .entry import ArchiveEntry
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import ffi
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
        libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
        return self._dlltype(name)
      File "C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

`$ C:\Users\amy\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py info`


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

Upload successful.
```

I tried these commands both on cmd and anaconda prompt. 
But I keep getting OSError :[WinError 126]

My computer environment is 64-bit Windows10 python 3.7.3
How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Conda? Also, even if Conda is broken and you don't remember your recent changes, you can still manually inspect the transaction history by looking at `conda-meta/history`. Your error seems to be related to the newer package archives they started using in 3.7 (i.e., `libarchive` package), specifically some compiled components. I'd look through the history for recent changes in `conda`, `python`, `libarchive`, or `cython`, and update your question with whatever might seem relevant.

Answer (score 0):

For resolving this above problem, We have 2 Ways :

1 - You can work with "**Anaconda Prompt**" separately

Press "**Windows**" Button and search "**Anaconda Prompt**" and Use it.
 "**conda info**" command will be executed successfully.

2 - You can also use "**Command Prompt**"

First, Select your Installation path of "**Anaconda**" (in which the folder "Anaconda" folder is present).

Complete Path : **C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3**

For Example: **Use this Path => C:\ProgramData**

Now, After setting up your path, you have to use the command "**activate root**".

For Example: Path => **C:\ProgramData> activate root**

Now you will get "**(base)**" as a prefix in the path.

For Example: Path => **(base) C:\ProgramData>**

Now, we can execute "**conda info**" command.

For Example: Path => **(base) C:\ProgramData>conda info**